# What is this possibly carnivorous plant with small purple flowers?

Tags: identification

I recently got this plant from a friend, but I never got the name of it. I think from the looks of it, it might be in the carnivore family.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That plant is not looking well. It might be a venus flytrap grown under very low light.  Can you provide a close up of the end of the leaf?

Comment: I will take a picture tomorrow in the better sunlight. However, I do have a flytrap as well and the differences between the 2 are big. The only reason why I suspect this is a carnivore plant is cause there is a small drosera plant growing on the side.

Comment: VFT's normally have white flowers.  Its in rough shape whatever it is.  Some drosera's have lavender flowers so this could be the mother plant to the smaller one.

Comment: Looks a bit like a very unhappy sundew, but even if the pictures didn't show it I'd guess you would have mentioned the leaf hairs in that case, so unless new pictures show otherwise... IM limited E I suspect you have low odds of pulling it through from where it's at; but perhaps that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing wildly here, but it looks like a pitcher plant, and not a *Nepenthes* (because their pitchers are sort of recurved extensions to the leaf rather than the whole leaf themselves), so something in Sarraceniaceae... the flowers don't look "wrong" to me, but I am not an expert...

Comment: the flower structurally looks ok, but all of the examples I am seeing are pendulous... rather than an erect panicle.

Answer (score 0):

Wait nevermind it's probably a Utricularia lateriflora which is a type of bladder wart flower. They are carnivorous and this is only one type in the Utricularia family.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Do NOT fertilize it.

If you think it's a carnivore, then it needs very acid, very low nutrient soil.  All the ones I'm familiar with grow in bogs -- damp sphagnum moss and peat.  They are tough to keep happy in modern dry houses.

Comment: all good suggestions but the question is what kind of carnivorous plant is it?

Comment: The OP 'thought' it might be a carnivore.  I was giving him criteria to help decide if it was a carnivore or not.